# WPF Assemblies on server

Tags: .net, wpf, windows

For image processing purposes, I'm using a few WPF assemblies Windows Server. I'm planning to deploy my application with PresentationCore.dll, WindowsBase.dll and System.Xaml.dll.

Now, before I do this, are there any technical or legal implications against doing this? I feel emotionally handicapped by having to put client-side stuff on the server, but some WPF classes are really handy for image processing. Any ideas?

pom

Comment: why would anyone vote this question down? not even leaving a comment for doing so. I'm clueless...

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of *potential* technical issues you could get into depending on the scenario but in general there's no blanket prohibition from using things from those assemblies and if you're just cherry picking a few things that aren't the main UI framework you should be fine.

As far as legal, I'm not a lawyer but: you're running Windows, so as long as the OS is paid for there shouldn't be any problem. Full .NET is included as an optional part of the platform anyway, usually even as an automatic update.